# WSO2 API Analytics - how to invoke Abnormal request pattern on purpose

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-streaming-integrator

We are having WSO2 APIM (still on 2.6.0) and as a PoC I tried to see the analytics (api-analytics 2.6.0 on MySQL). The analytics are collected, displayed, all seems to work good.

On the DEV environment we have following err messages:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcBatchUpdateException: Value too long for column "MESSAGE VARCHAR(254)": "'Abnormal request pattern detected by user :xxxxxx@yyyyyyyy@carbon.super using application : xxxxxUAT owned by: xxxx... (260)"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO ApimAllAlert (type , tenantDomain , message , severity , alertTimestamp  ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [22001-196]
```

I see these issues has been fixed in the newer versions (just after releasing v2.6.0), however the client doesn't have subscription for the analytics server, it's still a PoC. Seems fixed in v 3.x

Question: how could I invoke the `Abnormal request pattern` alert on purpose to conclude the issue is solved ?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the generate alert message is expected than the defined column length. to fix that you can manually increase column length as follow.

```
ALTER TABLE ApimAllAlert MODIFY message varchar(3000);
```

you can refer to this doc[1] to identify the scenario this alert type is generated.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Alert+Types#AlertTypes-Abnormalrequestcounts

Comment: thanks.. through just extending a message length will not help itself, there are multiple tables and other issues (too long key, ..) which are fixed in the 3.x. The most helpful part is the reference (link), though I'm still unable to get the *Abnormal request pattern* yet